# Handle ajax request with Django LoginRequiredMixin after session timeout

Tags: python, ajax, django

This situation was covered in other posts, but in most cases solutions are outdated and apply only to function-based views.

My problem is simple:
Right now my app enforces session timeouts on Django site with this parameters:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 600
```

And most of views utilize LoginrequiredMixin.
It works fine, but with the AJAX it obviously won't work. The common solution found over internet is changing the behaviour of authentication control to return 403. Is it possible to super the LoginRequiredMixin to do so for ajax requests? Or maybe just giveup and do this fully with javascript, on client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
     def handle_no_permission(self):
         if not self.request.is_ajax():
             return super().handle_no_permission()
         return JsonResponse({
             'code': 'Auth Required',
             'message': 'Session timeout!'
         }, status=401)
```

Comment: Ideally create a new mixin inheriting from LoginRequiredMixin so that it's reusable.